# Kirchhoff equations and matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There are many methods for solving linear circuits of electric current. Ultimately, all of them are converted to the Kirchhoff equations. For any electrical circuit, a corresponding matrix is constructed and a system of linear equations is solved.

But the most interesting begins after the decision. A non-linear (currents are squared) verification of the fulfillment of the law of conservation of energy is performed as a criterion for a correctly solved system of equations.

The question is - what specific mathematical property (from the point of view of linear algebra or matrix theory) ensures the fulfillment of the nonlinear law of conservation of energy?

From the point of view of physics, everything is clear ... But how can this be formulated from the point of view of mathematics?

Sorry for <s>poor</s> google English :)

Comment: It would be so helpful If you wrote down explictly these equations

Comment: When you say "linear circuits" don't you mean "resistive circuits" ?

Comment: Typically resistors, capacitors, inductors, and sources.

Comment: OK, limited to resistors (it really doesn't matter much). As regards the Kirchhoff equations, it is difficult to present the complete theory here. Briefly, there is a graph whose nodes have values (potentials U), and edges have resistances R. The current through the edge is defined as (U1-U2)/R, and the sums of currents at the nodes are zero. Honestly, I was hoping for those who know what the Kirchhoff equations are, because any particular system of equations does not say anything.